# How can I plot training accuracy, training loss with respect to epochs? I'm using pre-addestr Google bert

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, graph, loss

I am new to machine learning programming. I want to plot training accuracy, training loss, validation accuracy, and validation loss in following program.

I use some tutorials to do this, it work fine, but I want this graph

````
import tensorflow as tf

device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# install
!pip install pytorch-pretrained-bert pytorch-nlp
!pip install awscli awsebcli botocore==1.18.18 --upgrade

# BERT imports
import torch
import keras
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer, BertConfig
from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertAdam, BertForSequenceClassification
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from tqdm import tqdm, trange
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# % matplotlib inline

# specify GPU device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
n_gpu = torch.cuda.device_count()
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)

# Upload the train file from your local drive
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

df = pd.read_csv("text.tsv", delimiter='\t', header=None, names=['sentence_source', 'sentence', 'label', 'label_notes'])

df.shape

df.sample(19)

# Create sentence and label lists
sentences = df.sentence.values

# We need to add special tokens at the beginning and end of each sentence for BERT to work properly

sentences = ["[CLS] " + sentence + " [SEP]" for sentence in sentences]
labels = df.label.values

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)

tokenized_texts = [tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
print ("Tokenize the first sentence:")
print (tokenized_texts[0])

# Set the maximum sequence length. The longest sequence in our training set is 47, but we'll leave room on the end anyway. 
# In the original paper, the authors used a length of 512.
MAX_LEN = 128

# Use the BERT tokenizer to convert the tokens to their index numbers in the BERT vocabulary
input_ids = [tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(x) for x in tokenized_texts]

# Pad our input tokens
input_ids = pad_sequences(input_ids, maxlen=MAX_LEN, dtype="long", truncating="post", padding="post")

# Create attention masks
attention_masks = []

# Create a mask of 1s for each token followed by 0s for padding
for seq in input_ids:
  seq_mask = [float(i>0) for i in seq]
  attention_masks.append(seq_mask)

# Use train_test_split to split our data into train and validation sets for training

train_inputs, validation_inputs, train_labels, validation_labels = train_test_split(input_ids, labels, 
                                                            random_state=2018, test_size=0.1, stratify=labels)
train_masks, validation_masks, _, _ = train_test_split(attention_masks, input_ids,
                                             random_state=2018, test_size=0.1, stratify=labels)
#stratify

# Convert all of our data into torch tensors, the required datatype for our model
  
train_inputs = torch.tensor(train_inputs)
validation_inputs = torch.tensor(validation_inputs)
train_labels = torch.tensor(train_labels)
validation_labels = torch.tensor(validation_labels)
train_masks = torch.tensor(train_masks)
validation_masks = torch.tensor(validation_masks)

# Select a batch size for training. For fine-tuning BERT on a specific task, the authors recommend a batch size of 16 or 32
batch_size = 32

# Create an iterator of our data with torch DataLoader. This helps save on memory during training because, unlike a for loop, 
# with an iterator the entire dataset does not need to be loaded into memory

train_data = TensorDataset(train_inputs, train_masks, train_labels)
train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_data)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)

validation_data = TensorDataset(validation_inputs, validation_masks, validation_labels)
validation_sampler = SequentialSampler(validation_data)
validation_dataloader = DataLoader(validation_data, sampler=validation_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)

"""### **TRAIN**"""

# Load BertForSequenceClassification, the pretrained BERT model with a single linear classification layer on top. 

model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=5)
model.cuda()

param_optimizer = list(model.named_parameters())
no_decay = ['bias', 'gamma', 'beta']
optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
    {'params': [p for n, p in param_optimizer if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
     'weight_decay_rate': 0.01},
    {'params': [p for n, p in param_optimizer if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
     'weight_decay_rate': 0.0}
]

# This variable contains all of the hyperparemeter information our training loop needs
optimizer = BertAdam(optimizer_grouped_parameters,
                     lr=2e-5,
                     warmup=.1)

# Function to calculate the accuracy of our predictions vs labels
def flat_accuracy(preds, labels):
    pred_flat = np.argmax(preds, axis=1).flatten()
    labels_flat = labels.flatten()
    return np.sum(pred_flat == labels_flat) / len(labels_flat)

t = [] 

# Store our loss and accuracy for plotting
train_loss_set = []

# Number of training epochs (authors recommend between 2 and 4)
epochs = 1

# trange is a tqdm wrapper around the normal python range
for _ in trange(epochs, desc="Epoch"):
  
  
  # Training
  
  # Set our model to training mode (as opposed to evaluation mode)
  model.train()
  
  # Tracking variables
  tr_loss = 0
  nb_tr_examples, nb_tr_steps = 0, 0
  
  # Train the data for one epoch
  for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    # Add batch to GPU
    batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
    # Unpack the inputs from our dataloader
    b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch
    # Clear out the gradients (by default they accumulate)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # Forward pass
    loss = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
    train_loss_set.append(loss.item())    
    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()
    # Update parameters and take a step using the computed gradient
    optimizer.step()

    
    
    # Update tracking variables
    tr_loss += loss.item()
    nb_tr_examples += b_input_ids.size(0)
    nb_tr_steps += 1

  print("Train loss: {}".format(tr_loss/nb_tr_steps))
    
    
  # Validation

  # Put model in evaluation mode to evaluate loss on the validation set
  model.eval()

  # Tracking variables 
  eval_loss, eval_accuracy = 0, 0
  nb_eval_steps, nb_eval_examples = 0, 0

  # Evaluate data for one epoch
  for batch in validation_dataloader:
    # Add batch to GPU
    batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
    # Unpack the inputs from our dataloader
    b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch
    # Telling the model not to compute or store gradients, saving memory and speeding up validation
    with torch.no_grad():
      # Forward pass, calculate logit predictions
      logits = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask)
    
    # Move logits and labels to CPU
    logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
    label_ids = b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()

    tmp_eval_accuracy = flat_accuracy(logits, label_ids)
    
    eval_accuracy += tmp_eval_accuracy
    nb_eval_steps += 1
  print("Validation Accuracy: {}".format(eval_accuracy/nb_eval_steps))

# plot training performance
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.title("Training loss")
plt.xlabel("Batch")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.plot(train_loss_set)
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tensorboard` within Google Colab

```
#this loads Tensorboard notebooks extension so it displays inline
%load_ext tensorboard
...
#This will show tensorboard before training begins and it will update as training continues
%tensorboard --logdir logs

...

#training code
```

Google's officialy guidelines are here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb

Comment: Hello, thanks you for your answer.
I can't understand where put this code and what i have to change in my code, can you help me?